# Автоматическое обновление контента из бд

Tags: mysqli, php

Есть некая страница **news.php**. На этой странице выводятся заголовки новостей из базы данных, из таблицы **news**. Нужно, чтобы на странице **news.php** все обновлялось, как только будет добавлена новая запись в бд, т.е. новость. Прошу, не предлагайте варианты с автообновлением блоков на jQuery, это сильно нагружает. Мне нужно найти простой и оптимальный вариант для данной задачи, который можно будет применять как ядро (например, система обмена личными сообщениями). Подскажите какую-либо документацию, желательно с примерами. *А у кого время есть — Добрый Человек, напиши расширенный ответ!*

Comment: websockets посмотрите,

Comment: ajax запросы отправляй.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...WebSocket, но это будет создавать еще большую нагрузку (касается только сокетов).

WebSocket снимают нагрузку с сервера , long polling ,Comet, ajax наоборот увеличивают

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно использовать следующую логику:

1. Загружаем страницу с новостями.
2. Каждые n секунд (зависит от допустимой нагрузки на сервер) javascript отправляет ajax запрос на сервер, в котором параметром указан id или время самой свежей новости на странице.
3. Если новых новостей нет, сервер отправляет пустой ответ, иначе - данные новостей (обычно JSON или XML).
4. (Если получены данные новостей) JavaScript добавляет новые новости в ленту.

Система личных сообщений в ВК работает примерно так.

*Касательно того, что jQuery сильно нагружает:*

Если речь идет о нагрузке библиотеки на машины клиента, то, к сожалению, тут мало что можно сделать. В большинстве случаев это проблемы не конкретно jQuery, а машины клиента в целом. Хотя если написанный на jQuery скрипт с успехом кладет большинство клиентов - скорее всего, это ошибка в написании скрипта.

Если речь идет о нагрузке на сервер, то у меня только 1 совет: кэшируйте.

Answer (score 2):

Один select запрос при MyISAM - это ничтожно мало (с правильными индексами), при условии, что дергается только заголовок + mysql сама "кэширует" запросы. Есть вариант с [long polling](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/) или [WebSocket](http://habrahabr.ru/post/82140/), но это будет создавать еще большую нагрузку (касается только сокетов). Если уж так и хочется (что аж горит) оптимизировать и в ядро, то вот Вам [Comet](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79189/). Ну и, наверное, приведу решение на jQuery, для очистки совести. :)

```
<script>
    function show()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/last10.php", // Путь к php скрипту который будет загружать заголовки
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#lasttenposts").html(html); // Блок куда будем выводить информацию
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        show();
        setInterval(show, 5000); // Интервал обновления в миллисекундах 
    });
</script>
```

Сюда будем выводить результат:

```
<div id="lasttenposts"></div>
```

Ну, немного про "кэширование" в php,  [Memcached](http://habrahabr.ru/post/108274/).

Comment:     setInterval('show()',5000);

\>< >< >< ><

    setInterval(show,5000);

Comment: да, так более корректно.

Answer (score 1):

если говорить о нагрузке на сервер - то websocket даёт самую минимальную, мало того, информация на клиенте может обноалятся только при изменении данных на сервере - сервер сам разошлет "подписчикам" нужную инфу. если источник информации редкий то сервер будет курить бамбук(что свойственно для новостей). ajax запросы будут долбить сервер постоянно.

Comment: не могу найти как же все таки реализовать простой пример на PHP websockets. На локальном сервере, например.

Comment: https://github.com/wkjagt/Extendible-Web-Socket-Server , это один из некоторых на php. непосредственно с php не работал. но по работе с websocket могу помочь.

Comment: https://github.com/dvdrtrgn/ref/blob/master/_html/rc152-010d-Websocket_2.pdf 
там есть более полный список серверов под разные языки и есть графие сравнения нагрузки на сервер

Comment: А вообще Websockets используют только PHP или нужно ещё дополнить скрипт js ?

Comment: на клиенте, в браузере, php не существует - там, как правило, javascript. Для ws нужен не большой код - для инициализации протокола , обработки отправления, обработки приема. Это стандартные вещи. но это только для современных браузеров. Для старых ишаков и пр. недо.. есть эмуляторы ws на флэш. Кроме того надо организовать "внутренний протокол" - т.к. ws обеспечивают только канал передачи. самое простое передавать json, на приёмных концах его "декодировать" и выполнять соответствующие действия.
в отличии от ajax - запрашивать от клиента наличие информации не надо.